# How to hide Gmail labels in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, imap

When searching for mail in Mail.app with a Gmail account, every instance of the mail shows up with every Gmail label, especially in the Bin label, since Apple mail autosaves drafts as you go along, there can be 50 instances of a single mail just in the Bin folder.

This makes searching impossible.

So I'm trying to turn off those labels in Gmail but no success so far. I have disabled "Show in IMAP" option in the Gmail label settings for all those labels then deleted all the cached items in ~/Library/Mail/V2 and restarted Mail.app but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: A workaround: Create a new top-level mailbox in the Mail.app and move the labels that need to be hidden into it and then collapse it. It remains collapsed after restarting the app. A small issue is that it appears in Gmail as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you use this tutorial to make GMail and Mail.app work together. The key for me was disabling the "All Mail" label, which was causing havoc in my mail setup.

[LINK](http://jeffschuette.com/2012/03/07/setting-up-apple-mail-to-rock-and-roll-with-gmail/)

Comment: The link is dead. Answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Those folders are for your convenience, can be deleted in Mail -- or under the Mailbox menu, you can choose "Use this folder for" ...

Comment: When a folder is deleted in the Mail.app, it gets removed from Gmail labels too.